# Want to render or generate all php files in a directory to static html

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a mini web project for a local business. I used PHP includes and plain PHP templates for this as I found CMSs too big for the task.

I'm trying to generate all `.php` files in the project dir to static .html using ob_start(), ob_get_contents() like:

```
ob_start();
$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$out = "pages/page-1";
$file = $out.'/'. "filename.html";
@chmod($file,0755);
$fw = fopen($file, "w");
fputs($fw,$page, strlen($page));
fclose($fw);
```

This generates the current page (where the code is written) but I'm stuck with doing this manually for all `.php` files instead of adding it to every page.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the basic structure:

```
- index.php
- /about
 --- about-us.php
 --- our-story.php
- /products
 --- interior/
  --- some-product.php
 --- exterior/
  --- some-product.php
  --- some-other-product.php
- /contact
 --- contact.php
 --- quote.php
- /includes (config,base.php,header.tpl,footer.tpl,...templates)
- /css/js/images/assets...
```

I will put the script in the same folder and it shouldn't render itself, the html output will go to the /out folder.

Comment: Look into the use of `glob` to iterate through all files in a directory.

Comment: Thanks! glob made the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bare-bones implementation of a script that:

1. Looks for `.php` files in a directory
2. Runs each `.php` file
3. Dumps the output to a `.html` file with the same name

This is not recursive, but I don't have enough information about the structure of your site to make too many assumptions.

If you update your question I can update my answer - you can use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and the aptly-named `RecursiveRecursiveIterator` to recurse through a file structure.

In any case, this should provide a starting point:

```
<?php

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);

function isValidFile(SplFileInfo $fileInfo)
{
    return $fileInfo->isFile()
        && 'php' === $fileInfo->getExtension()
        && basename(__FILE__) !== $fileInfo->getBasename();
}

function parseFile(SplFileInfo $fileInfo)
{
    ob_start();
    require_once $fileInfo->getBasename();
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $data;
}

foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
    if (isValidFile($fileInfo)) {
        $data = parseFile($fileInfo);
        $file = $fileInfo->getBasename('.php') . '.html';
        file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }
}
```

Given a file structure like this:

[image]

You should end up with the following (assuming that dir is writable):

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No problem! If you want to provide any more detail that helps to better answer your question I'll be glad to update the answer :)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I am another person, this is not my question, I am just a looker for this answer, and I liked the solution, My point was that I am happy for the solution and I will keep it as reference for future use, and will vote up for your answer, but I have used all my vote ups today, have to wait for few hours. that is it.

Comment: Ah... Haha sorry! I didn't even compare usernames! No worries anyway, cheers!

Comment: @Darragh Thank you for your answer it was helpful. I tried to vote up but it is not possible. I updated my question. I still have a problem with the includes in .php files. I think I should make a `base.php` and put: `define('WS_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('INC_ROOT', WS_ROOT . "/inc");`
Also how can I keep the same structure for the html output? Using `DirectoryIterator::isDir`

Comment: Morning! I just saw your update. I'll have a look and update my answer to reflect your question more accurately. I might also have an alternative solution. Regarding resolving paths, we might have to figure that out. How are you defining these includes in your .php files? Incidentally, if you are using PHP >= 5.3 you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`;